# Canvas and Javascript update rect and display custom text string

Tags: javascript, string, html, canvas, text

I want the user to click a resize button which changes the size of a rectangle, but also modifies a text string to announce the new size and the square inches as well... see comments within the code...

the html doc....

```
<input type="button" id="increaseBoxWidth" value="Make Box Wider">
<input type="button" id="decreaseBoxWidth" value="Make Box Narrower">
<input type="button" id="increaseBoxHeight" value="Make Box Taller">
<input type="button" id="decreaseBoxHeight" value="Make Box Shorter">
```

and then the javascript.....

```
window.addEventListener("load", eventWindowLoaded, false);

function eventWindowLoaded () {
    initializeThings();
}

function initializeThings() {
    ... canvas, context and such.....
    var boxWidth = 5;
    var boxHeight = 3;
    var boxSquareInches = 15;
    var message = "box is 5 inches wide and 3 inches tall... and the total square inches is 15"

... is only one "var" declared for all these listeners?

    var formElement = document.getElementById("increaseBoxWidth");
    formElement.addEventListener('click', boxWider, false);

    formElement = document.getElementById("decreaseBoxWidth");
    formElement.addEventListener('click', boxNarrower, false);

    formElement = document.getElementById("increaseBoxHeight");
    formElement.addEventListener('click', boxTaller, false);

    formElement = document.getElementById("decreaseBoxHeight");
    formElement.addEventListener('click', boxShorter, false);

    function boxWider(){
        if (boxWidth < 10) {
            boxWidth += 1;
            boxSquareInches = boxWidth * boxHeight;


        message = "Hey there... your new box size is + boxWidth + inches by + boxHeight+ inches... and the total square inches is + boxSquareInches +"

drawScreen()
        }
    }
/// THREE MORE FUNCTIONS???? FOR NARROWER, TALLER AND SHORTER????

    function drawScreen(){
        ...
        context.fillRect(0,0,boxWidth,boxHeight);
        context.fillText (message, 10, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question. We are not mind-readers. Please tell us what is happening vs what *should* be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... is only one "var" declared for all these listeners?

No, each element needs to be declared with a unique name, otherwise, your program can't differentiate when user clicks one button or the other. Something like this:

```
var iw = document.getElementById("increaseBoxWidth");
iw.addEventListener('click', boxWider, false);

var dw = document.getElementById("decreaseBoxWidth");
dw.addEventListener('click', boxNarrower, false);

var ih = document.getElementById("increaseBoxHeight");
ih.addEventListener('click', boxTaller, false);

var dh = document.getElementById("decreaseBoxHeight");
dh.addEventListener('click', boxShorter, false);
```

> /// THREE MORE FUNCTIONS???? FOR NARROWER, TALLER AND SHORTER????

Yes, that would be the next thing to do. Just like you did for `boxWider()`

**Note on your string:** You need to break apart the string in order to have the variables concatenated with your text. In other words, the `+` sign and variable names do not go inside the quotes. Like this:

```
message = "Hey there... your new box size is" + boxWidth + "inches by" + boxHeight + "inches... and the total square inches is" + boxSquareInches;
```

**Additional note:** In JavaScript, you start a comment with two `//` not with `...`

Hope that helps.